# How to get JDBC binding parameters from Hibernate in JBoss 7?

Tags: hibernate, debugging, jboss7.x

I'm trying simply to get the values that Hibernate is binding to the queries behind the question marks "?" on JBoss 7.

So I'm editing `standalone/configuration/logging.properties` in order to add this :

```
logger.org.hibernate=DEBUG
logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL
```

But I get nothing in my console, nor in the log file... what am I missing ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Wow, it's not really like the previous versions... I've finally found the [offical way to configure JBoss 7 logging](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Logging+configuration) and the [logging configuration of Hibernate 4](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-logging) !

What you have to do is edit `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` (the configuration file of your `domain`) and search for the `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">` tag.

Then in the `<console-handler name="CONSOLE"`, I've switched the level information to TRACE (`<level name="TRACE"`) and added the `<logger category="org.hibernate">`.

Here is the partial XML :

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
    <console-handler name="CONSOLE" autoflush="true">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </console-handler>
    ...
    <logger category="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder">
        <level name="TRACE"/>
    </logger>
    ...
```

---

I've found another and better (because it logs all the JDBC method calls, not only basic binding) solution from [a blog post](http://czetsuya-tech.blogspot.fr/2014/05/how-to-monitor-data-source-connections.html#.VR0OhR96-kA): add `spy="true"` in the `<datasource>` declaration and `TRACE` logs from category `jboss.jdbc.spy`:

```xml
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" pool-name="myPool" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" spy="true" use-ccm="true">
```

and the logger (in `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">`):

```xml
<logger category="jboss.jdbc.spy">
    <level name="TRACE"/>
</logger>
```