# How to manually set the @Version fields with Hibernate 4?

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, optimistic-locking, jboss7.x

**Environment:**

I have that `User` entity :

```java
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer userId;

    @Version
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "VERSION", length = 19)
    private Date version;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String login;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

I have a search page which lists users, then I click on a user to edit it (giving its `userId` in the URL).

In the edit form, I store on the server the fields of that entity and when I save my User I do this :

```java
User user = entityManager.find(User.class, userId)
user.setLogin(form.getLogin());
user.setVersion(form.getVersion());
user.setUserId(form.getUserId());
entityManager.merge(user);
```

**Question:**

So if I correctly understood optimistic locking with Hibernate, if I open 2 tabs in my browser to edit the same user, **then** update the login on the first tab, and **then** the login on the second tab, I should have an `OptimisticLockException` shouldn't I ?

Actually, this is not the case on my application... I verified, the `form.getVersion()` return the same value in both case, even if that in the second update, the `user.version` has been updated by the first edit.

Am I missing something ?

The `EntityManager` is produced `@RequestScoped` (so I'm on two different `EntityManager`s when I try to merge...).

I've tried to do a `entityManager.lock(user, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT)` before `entityManager.merge(...)` ([as said here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299430/updating-hibernate-version-manually)), but it didn't help.

I'm using Seam 3 with JBoss 7.0.2.Final (which uses Hibernate 4).

Comment: Are you sure the entityManager is flushed (or the transaction is committed)? What's the generated SQL update query?

Comment: Yes, with the [activation of Hibernate SQL dumping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9159752/how-to-get-jdbc-binding-parameters-from-hibernate-in-jboss-7) I can see the SQL update and the JDBC `version` field binding which doesn't correspond to the `version` I set in the `User` in the `WHERE id = ? AND version = ?`... I've developped a `FlushInterceptor` which is called after my `update` function exists and which does an `entityManager.flush()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually I've found a way to do that... but I think it's not really efficient (because there is 1 more SELECT request).

```java
User user = entityManager.find(User.class, userId)
user.setLogin(form.getLogin());
user.setVersion(form.getVersion());
user.setUserId(form.getUserId());

entityManager.detach(user);
entityManager.merge(user);
```

With **`entityManager.detach(user)`**, hibernate now uses my setted `version` value instead of its own copied somewhere value...

Answer (score 7):

I just did some more research on this.

It is **not allowed to modify the version field** according to the JPA spec:

JPA 2.0 Final Spec, Section 3.4.2:

> An entity may access the state of its version field or property or export a method for use by the application to access the version, but **must not modify the version value**. With the exception noted in section 4.10, **only the persistence provider is permitted to set or update the value** of the version attribute in the object.

Note: Section 4.10 refers to batch updates which ignore the version attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Found another way of triggering optimistic locking manually. We can compare the cached Hibernate version with the version in the entity. I'm using spring data JPA, and added the ff. to the repository save implementation:

```
EntityEntry entityEntry = entityManager
  .unwrap(SessionImplementor.class)
  .getPersistenceContext()
  .getEntry(entity);

//checked if a cached entry is present
if (entityEntry != null) {

  //Compare cached version with the one in the entity
  if (!Objects.equals(entityEntry.getVersion(), classMetadata.getVersion(entity))) {
    throw new ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException();
  }
}
```